# express-mysql-session not storing sessions

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, session, session-cookies

I am new to express and mySQL so this could be an obvious thing I am missing. I have a very simple express server that should store session data to a mySQl server, using the express-mysql-session module. I have a table already created in the sessions-test database, and from the documentation I've read, it seems that loading up localhost:3000 should store the current session into the table. However, nothing is inserted.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const session = require("express-session");
const mySQlStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session);


const app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'myBooks',
    socketPath: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
});


const sessionStore = new mySQlStore({
    database: 'sessions-test',
}, connection);

app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
    name: 'my_cookie',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    createDatabaseTable: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000
    }
}));

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("<h1>Hello</h1>")
})

app.listen(3000);
```

`

I have also tried following the exact demo code from the documentation which was supposed to create a new table under sessions-test. When that didn't work, I tried the following SQL query to manually create the table in phpMyAdmin, but the table is still not populating with sessions data.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `expires` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Thank you in advance for your help!